# SPException while updating SPItem

Tags: c#, exception, sharepoint, updating

I'm writing code for SharePoint 2010 with VisualStudio 2013 Premium
I have created a buttonclick event in a webpart, which should update a exsisting item in the list...but at the moment I press this button, i get spexception was unhandled by user code..

Here is a piece of code I've created:

```
void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.GetList["MyList"];
    SPItem item = list.GetItemById(myId);

    item["MyField"] = newValue;
    item.Update;
}
```

At the same time I tried not to update, but to create a new item with the same Value of the Field and it Executed...

Any ideas, what's the problem with this?

Comment: spexception was unhandled by user code

Comment: Please check ULS log for exact details of this exception.

Comment: The problem is that I can't even update an item with standart SharePoint Item Editor..I get the same error..At the same time I can update items of any other lists...

Answer (score 2):

I guess, You get an error because `SPItem` is an abstract class and while obtaining specific item from the list, You definitely should use `SPListItem` class. And, probably, this is a misprint but `Update` is a method, so your code should look like this:

```
SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(myId); 
item["MyField"] = newValue;
item.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem look like, you have don't have write the correct list name or field name.

Please assure that you are not updating the ID field. Can you tell the exactly line where you are getting the exception?

Comment: An exception I get exactly on line item.Update

Comment: It will only be guessing if you don't want to give us the exact exception from the ULS log...

Answer (score 0):

Try to create new instanse of site and web from current context, and set their AllowUnsafeUpdates to true, like that:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))                   
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        SPList list = web.GetList["MyList"];
        SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(myId);

        item["MyField"] = newValue;
        item.Update();

        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
}
```